# Как удалить Inline клавиатуру Aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram

Подскажите как мне удалить(или скрыть) клавиатуру после нажатия на нее?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно вот так. В колбеке который ловит нажатие этой кнопки, обратитесь к объекту message через callbackQuery и вызовите метод для изменения reply_markup (короче клавиатуры) никакие аргументы не передавайте.

```py
@dp.callback_query_handler(text="asd")
async def asd(call:types.CallbackQuery):
    await call.message.edit_reply_markup()
```